# How can I make PHP handle functions' overloading errors?

Tags: php, error-handling

Lets assume I have a class called `Form`. This class uses the magic method `__call()` to add fields to itself like so:

```
<?php
class Form {

  private $_fields = array();

  public function __call($name, $args) {

    // Only allow methods which begin with 'add'
    if ( preg_match('/^add/', $name) ) {

       // Add a new field

    } else {

       // PHP throw the default 'undefined method' error

    }

  }  

}
```

My problem is that I can't figure out how to make PHP handle the calls to undefined methods in it's default way. Of course, the default behavior can be mimicked in many ways, for example I use the following code right now:

```
trigger_error('Call to undefined method ' . __CLASS__ . '::' . $function, E_USER_ERROR);
```

But I don't like this solution because the error itself or its level might change in the future, so is there a better way to handle this in PHP?

**Update**
Seems like my question is a little vague, so to clarify more... How can I make PHP throw the default error for undefined methods *without* the need to supply the error and it's level? The following code won't work in PHP, but it's what I'm trying to do:

```
// This won't work because my class is not a subclass. If it were, the parent would have             
// handled the error 
parent::__call($name, $args);

// or is there a PHP function like...
trigger_default_error(E_Undefined_Method);
```

If anyone is familiar with ruby, this can be achieved by calling the `super` method inside `method_missing`. How can I replicate that in PHP?

Answer (score 1):

Use exceptions, that's what they're for

```
public function __call($name, $args) {
   // Only allow methods which begin with 'add'
    if ( preg_match('/^add/', $name) ) {
       // Add a new field
    } else {
       throw new BadMethodCallException('Call to undefined method ' . __CLASS__ . '::' . $name);
    }
}
```

This is then trivially easy to catch

```
try {
    $form->foo('bar');
} catch (BadMethodCallException $e) {
    // exception caught here
    $message = $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this still means that I have to supply the error message. I want PHP to use its default one.

Comment: @Maher4Ever Why? It's your class, not PHP's. You could always omit the message all together, that exception is pretty self-descriptive

Comment: If I want to hide how the class is implemented, I would have to generate a message that looks exactly like the one php uses, so that calling an undefined method would show the default error. That seems like repeating what php already does... I only want to access the default message and show it!

Comment: @Maher4Ever Hide it from whom? It's obvious your class is not a built-in one so why should it be any surprise that it has its own error messages? AFAIK, the PHP error messages are not available as a language resource or anything like that

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change error level, just change it when necessary or add if statement instead of `E_USER_ERROR`